# Odoo automatic method call in model

Tags: odoo

I have this model:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    _name = 'aibot.data'
    _description = 'aibot.data'
    symbol = fields.Char(string='Symbol', required=False)
    ref = fields.Float(string='Amount', required=False)
    amount = fields.Float(string='Amount', required=False)

    user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='User', required=True, ondelete='cascade',
                              default=lambda self: self.env.uid, help="User")
```

I have this python dict:

```
    m = [
        {'symbol': '2', 'ref': 7.8,  'amount': 87},
        {'symbol': '2', 'ref': 7.8,  'amount': 25},
        {'symbol': '2', 'ref': 7.8,  'amount': 31},
        {'symbol': '2', 'ref': 7.8,  'amount': 26},
        {'symbol': '2', 'ref': 7.8,  'amount': 90},
        {'symbol': '2', 'ref': 7.8,  'amount': -18}
    ]
```

And this method:

def rep(self):

```
 parse = 1
 self.search([('create_uid', '=', 'user.id')]).unlink()

 m = [
     {'symbol': '2', 'ref': 7.8,  'amount': 87},
     {'symbol': '2', 'ref': 7.8,  'amount': 25},
     {'symbol': '2', 'ref': 7.8,  'amount': 31},
     {'symbol': '2', 'ref': 7.8,  'amount': 26},
     {'symbol': '2', 'ref': 7.8,  'amount': 90},
     {'symbol': '2', 'ref': 7.8,  'amount': -18}
 ]

for i in m:
    print('hola', '')
    self.env['aibot.data'].create(i)
```

All works fine. But, I need automatic execution  of this method on Data class call from tree view, report..., to fill out the table before anything else.

Answer (score 0):

If table `aibot.data` is to hold report data lines of the report table, you can do the following to fill in automatically when the report object record will be created:

```
m = [
    {'symbol': '2', 'ref': 7.8,  'amount': 87},
    {'symbol': '2', 'ref': 7.8,  'amount': 25},
    {'symbol': '2', 'ref': 7.8,  'amount': 31},
    {'symbol': '2', 'ref': 7.8,  'amount': 26},
    {'symbol': '2', 'ref': 7.8,  'amount': 90},
    {'symbol': '2', 'ref': 7.8,  'amount': -18}
]

class Report(models.Model):
    _name = 'aibot.report'
    _description = 'this is the report object'

    # data lines for the report
    data_ids = fields.One2many('aibot.data','report_id')

    @api.model
    def default_get(self, fields_list):
        res = super().default_get(fields_list)
        data_ids = []
        for i in m:
            data_ids.append((0,0,i))
        res['data_ids'] = data_ids
        return res

class Data(models.Model):
    _name = 'aibot.data'

    report_id = fields.Many2one('aibot.report')
    symbol = fields.Char(string='Symbol', required=False)
    ref = fields.Float(string='Amount', required=False)
    amount = fields.Float(string='Amount', required=False)
```